Sampling orthogonal matrices with eigenvalues in given range?
Can anyone see a nice way to sample real orthogonal matrices whose eigenvalues are approximately uniform within a given range on a complex unit circle?
Below is a heuristic attempt to sample orthogonal matrices with eigenvalues in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ segment.
n = 200;
randn := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n}]/Sqrt[n];
polarDecomp = ResourceFunction["PolarDecomposition"];
ComplexListPlot[
 Eigenvalues[First@polarDecomp[IdentityMatrix[n] + randn]], 
 PlotRange -> {-1.1 - 1.1 I, 1.1 + 1.1 I}]


Motivation: this gives a way to sample rotations for a specific angle (since rotation of a random vector is determined by the average real part of eigenvalue), earlier post

To clarify: n is the size of a matrix? Or you want n tuple of random 2x2 rotation matrices?

$n$ is the size of the matrix

Let us assume the size $n$ of the wanted orthogonal matrix mat is even, $n=2k$. I will use the following fact: a real orthogonal matrix have a real Jordan normal form which is a direct sum of $k$-tuples of 2-dim rotation matrices.
So, my strategy is to go in the opposite direction to Jordan decomposition.
ClearAll["Global`*"];
n = 200;
anglerange = {2 Pi/6, 2 Pi/3};
blocks = 
  Table[R[i] -> RotationMatrix[RandomReal[anglerange]], {i, n/2}];
realJordanform = 
  ArrayFlatten@(DiagonalMatrix[Array[R, n/2]] /. blocks);
randomorthogonalmatrix := RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[n]];

p = randomorthogonalmatrix;

mat = Transpose[p] . realJordanform . p;
MatrixPlot[mat]


ComplexListPlot[Eigenvalues[mat], 
 PlotRange -> {-1.1 - 1.1 I, 1.1 + 1.1 I}, 
 Epilog -> {Arrow[{{0, 0}, AngleVector[#]}] & /@ 
    Join[anglerange, -anglerange]}]



neat trick with ArrayFlatten. BTW using QR decomposition creates a biased sample, I think it's better to use RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[n]], or manually flip signs as specified here or in higham's post

Thank you for your useful comment, and also for editing my answer accordingly. I tried to generate uniform distribution of Arg of eigenvalues, but paid little attention to the uniformity with respect to O(N) Haar measure...
